# Entering newline in a cedit control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, cedit

A very straightforward question....

How do you enter a new line in a `CEdit` control box without it triggering OK and closing the dialog box altogether? What I mean is when you hit the enter key it automatically selects OK, even if your cursor is still in the `CEdit` control. Is what I am trying to do possible? Or do i have to use some other control

PS: It is a modal dialog box btw.

Comment: In the dialog editor, set the "Multiline" and "Want Return" properties to True and it is all automagic from there.

Answer (score 3):

There are various solutions for this problem.

Basically what you need is the `ES_WANTRETURN` style on the edit control.

Another solution is to check the message and key in `PreTranslateMessage` (since it has been commented upon this is not the recommended way, I'm just mentioning it for possibilities):

```
BOOL CYouDialog::PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
{
    if (pMsg->message == WM_KEYDOWN && pMsg->wParam == VK_RETURN &&
        GetFocus() == youcontrol)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

The other solution is to handle `WM_GETDLGCODE`. You should subclass the edit control and do this:

```
UINT CYourEdit::OnGetDlgCode()
{
    return CEdit::OnGetDlgCode() | DLGC_WANTALLKEYS;
}
```

UPDATE: FYI, also have a look at [Just because you're a control doesn't mean that you're necessarily inside a dialog box](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/08/20/4470527.aspx).

Comment: After your days at CodeGuru, I'm surprised that you would recommend the [PreTranslateMessage hack](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?231075-MFC-Dialog-How-to-disable-change-the-behaviour-of-the-lt-gt-key-in-a-dialog)

Answer (score -1):

The default dialog processing, as you've discovered, is to close a dialog box when enter is pressed.  MFC actually executes the OnOK processing, but you can override that.  [Here's](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/122489) and old explanation, but, it's still relevant.

Comment: This would prevent you from closing the dialog with OK.